# Sticky Columns - Different Fonts/Boldness on same CSS

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-table

I'm trying to make a Table with 2 Sticky Columns on each side, and a few in the middle that can be moved.

While nearly everything is working, I have one small problem:

I will use `color:red;` in some TD's. For the example, I made them all red. If you try to compare the red text of a sticky column, and the red text of a non-sticky column, you can see they are different. How can I fix that?

```css
#MyTable {
  background-color: #333333;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-left: 0px;
  color: red;
}

#MyTable>thead>tr>th,
#MyTable>tbody>tr>td {
  min-width: 150px;
  max-width: 150px;
}

#MyTable>thead>tr>th:nth-child(1),
#MyTable>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(1) {
  color: red;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #333333;
}

#MyTable>thead>tr>th:nth-child(2),
#MyTable>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(2) {
  color: red;
  position: sticky;
  left: 150px;
  background-color: #333333;
}

#MyTable>thead>tr>th:nth-last-child(1),
#MyTable>tbody>tr>td:nth-last-child(1) {
  color: red;
  position: sticky;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #333333;
}

#MyTable>thead>tr>th:nth-last-child(2),
#MyTable>tbody>tr>td:nth-last-child(2) {
  color: red;
  position: sticky;
  right: 150px;
  background-color: #333333;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table id="MyTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1 Sticky</th>
      <th>Col 2 Sticky</th>
      <th>Col 3 Normal</th>
      <th>Col 4 Normal</th>
      <th>Col 5 Normal</th>
      <th>Col 6 Normal</th>
      <th>Col 7 Sticky</th>
      <th>Col 8 Sticky</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Test Data</td>
      <td>Test Data</td>
      <td>Test Data</td>
      <td>Test Data</td>
      <td>Test Data</td>
      <td>Test Data</td>
      <td>Test Data</td>
      <td>Test Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test Data</td>
      <td>Test Data</td>
      <td>Test Data</td>
      <td>Test Data</td>
      <td>Test Data</td>
      <td>Test Data</td>
      <td>Test Data</td>
      <td>Test Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test Data</td>
      <td>Test Data</td>
      <td>Test Data</td>
      <td>Test Data</td>
      <td>Test Data</td>
      <td>Test Data</td>
      <td>Test Data</td>
      <td>Test Data</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is a complete JSFiddle, showing the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/6afueqgb/

As for solutions - they need to only work on Chrome 80+. No IE, Edge or FF support is needed, in case that makes a difference.

Comment: Hello. In StackOverflow rules you're not allowed to ask multiple questions in a single question. Please remove one of the questions or the whole question will get closed.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy thanks, i edited it. how can i re-open the question?

Comment: No need for jsFiddle when we have [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552)! :)

Comment: I don't see any difference with the fonts. I also inspected the site and all your TD's are using Times 16px. Are you still trying to fix this?

Comment: I would say the fonts are the same, but it looks like under certain circumstances, the weight of the frozen columns becomes greater for some reason. I'm able to reproduce in Edge (Chromium) Version 82.0.432.3 (Official build) dev (64-bit) on Windows 10.

Comment: Yes, im still trying to solve this. And yes, it looks more like the weight is different, even when they have the same settings/styles